# Cannot change settings for keycloack account

Tags: keycloak

When I fill all required fields and try save account settings in [Keycloak Edit Account menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFV8S.png), I get an Internal Server Error in the UI:

[image: 2]

Simultaneously there are **no any error messages in logs** which could help to identify the source of this issue. I get the same error message for all parts of Edit Account menu (when I try to change password, log out session etc.)

Any ideas why it happens?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. For any specific problem you are having please include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Also, be sure to take the https://stackoverflow.com/tour (you get a badge!)

Answer (score 0):

With Keycloak 11.0.1 users can't edit their account.
Trying to save the form results in a 403 - Forbidden error.

Just update your version in 11.0.2 https://www.keycloak.org/downloads.html and follow the getting started guide
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/getting_started/

Comment: Can you provide more either an explanation for why this is occurring? Or if not, what documentation you are using for this conclusion? Unfortunately I am stuck with Keycloak 11.0.1 right now.